# Interchanging expectations of log likelihood

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, expected-value, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I see in papers ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.02718.pdf) in eq. 3 or [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.538.3608&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on page 4, for example) that it can be done like this using Fubini
$$\mathbb{E}_x\mathbb{E}_\theta\log f(x|\theta)=\mathbb{E}_\theta\mathbb{E}_x\log f(x|\theta)$$
Where $f(x|\theta)$ is a conditional probability density.

I don't immediately see why $\mathbb{E}_\theta\mathbb{E}_x|\log f(x|\theta)|\leq\infty$. Is it actually the case? Or are some additional conditions on $f$ needed?

Comment: Can you attach a couple, or at least one more paper where you see this exchange?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon added one paper.

Comment: Thank you very much for the second attachment. My very first thought was that the logarithm is concave, and therefore Jensen's inequality might be applied somewhere. Let me see if I can push this further.

Comment: thx for looking into this. Also $\ln(x)\leq x-1$ may be useful for the upper bound, but i don't see how to get uniform bounds with this or Jensen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identities
$$\mathbb{E}_x\mathbb{E}_\theta \bigl[{\bf 1}_{\{f(x|\theta)>1\}}\log f(x|\theta)  \bigr]=\mathbb{E}_\theta\mathbb{E}_x\bigl[{\bf 1}_{\{f(x|\theta)>1\}}\log f(x|\theta)  \bigr]\quad \; \; (*)$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}_x\mathbb{E}_\theta \bigl[{\bf 1}_{\{f(x|\theta)\le 1\}}\log f(x|\theta)  \bigr]=\mathbb{E}_\theta\mathbb{E}_x\bigl[{\bf 1}_{\{f(x|\theta)\le 1\}}\log f(x|\theta)  \bigr]\quad \; \; (**)$$
always hold by Tonelli's_theorem [1]. Adding them will give the desired formula,  provided at least one of them is finite.

On the other hand, if $(*)$ yields $+\infty$ and  $(**)$ yields $-\infty$, then the original formula might be undefined. For example,
consider the densities
$$f(x|\theta)=\frac{C}{|x-\theta |\, [1+(\log |x-\theta|)^2]} \,,$$
where $C$ is chosen to ensure $\int f(x|\theta) \, dx=1$.
(One can give an even simpler degenerate example, replacing $\theta$ on the RHS of  this formula by $0$.)
To verify the example, the integration fact needed is that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x (1 +(\log  x)^\beta)} $$
is finite for $\beta>1$ but infinite for $\beta=1$. The change of variable $u =\log x$ transforms this to the standard integrals
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{  (1 +u^\beta )} \,. $$
Similarly,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x (1 +|\log x|^\beta )} $$
is finite for $\beta>1$ but infinite for $\beta=1$.

[1]
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My integration skills are rusty, could you please elaborate your example?

Comment: You are correct! Indeed, in a couple of papers, this was very much taken as an assumption, see for example [here](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/7edccc661418aeb5761dbcdc06ad490c-Paper.pdf).The paper proceeds to elaborate upon the assumption, stating that it is relatively mild and is satisfied, for example if the parametrized densities are bounded.

Comment: Koncopd, I added more details on the integration in the example.

Comment: @YuvalPeres, thank you. Though i still can't see why $\mathbb{E}_x\ln\frac{1}{x(1+\ln^2(x))}\bf1_{\{x>1\}}$ and $\mathbb{E}_x\ln\frac{1}{x(1+\ln^2(x))}\bf1_{\{1\geq x>0\}}$are infinities with different signs.

Comment: Koncopd, did you try writing out the integral explicitly with the density, then doing a change of variable $u=\log x$?

Comment: If you write the first expectation as an integral, then the integrand is asymptotic to $-1/(x \log x)$ as $x \to \infty$, so by the comparison test [1] it suffices to consider the latter. Flipping sign, $\int_e^R  1/(x \log x)  \, dx= \log \log(R)$ tends to $\infty$  as $ R \to \infty$.
 
 [1] https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx